# Can't open specific URL in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

```
NSString *urlAddress;
urlAddress = @"http://ob.carptown.net";
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[page loadRequest:requestObj];
[page addSubview:activityView];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0)
                                         target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(loading)
                                       userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
goBack.enabled = page.canGoBack;
goNext.enabled = page.canGoForward;
```

The `UIViewView` can't open the above URL (http://ob.carptown.net).
I have tested another URL and `UIViewView` opened them. But the URL can open in Safari.
I want the URL to open safari and I want to control the safari as like `UIWebView`.

How would I do that?

Comment: Do you want the webView to open up within the app or transfer over to the standalone safari app?

Comment: i just want open the url(http://ob.carotown.net).

Comment: without leaving the app?

Comment: yes, without leaving without my app.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://ob.carptown.net";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[yourwebview loadRequest:requestObj];

remove NStimer and check it again it will work fine
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the HTML returned, the server is giving you an empty `<body>` tag (except for google analytics). Looks like you have javascript rendering the content after the page loads. The `UIWebView` seems to fail to execute this. Only when changing orientation from landscape and back  (`Cmd + left arrow` and `Cmd + right` arrow quickly after each other) does it reload the page. Unfortunately I have no clue why this is happening